How can I forward ports for applications using WireGuard?
I have 4 devices: 2 Desktops and 2 SmartPhones.. I'm trying to set up a mini home lab for learning purposes but networking is really hard to figure out for me hence is difficult to make my home network to work the way I want it.. (sorry for bad English..)
I'm using the oldest desktop as a wireguard server for the other 3 devices (1 desktop and 2 smartphones). The 4 devices are connected to the internet and the LAN by the same router.. Before using wireguard I used to forward ports in the router for the apps to get the ports opened when needed.. Almost every tutorial do not recommend to open ports router side while using wireguard so I only have the wireguard port open in the router..
However, I can't get the ports opened for the apps I commonly use like torrent apps and can't connect the smartphones to the desktop by GSConnect as usual, not even adding the devices by ip address..
Both desktops run Debian 12.. Note: I can connect to the server remotely by Gnome Connections app and use the server as a headless one..
Following some tutorials I use the following config:
Server:
/etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
Forwarding wg config:
PostUp = ufw route allow in on WireGuard out on eth0
PostUp = iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ufw route delete allow in on WireGuard out on eth0
PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
What could I do to get ports opened to the apps like transmission and others? Thanks!

Port forwarding in Wireguard itself is probably a red herring.  I don't believe Wireguard knows or cares about ports.   If you are trying to forward ports, at the tunnel which has the wireguard interface and public IP address you will want to add something like IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ethX -p tcp --dport 6881 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.2.0.1:6881   (Change ethX for the ethernet interface, and port 6881 and the IP as appropriate).   You may be able to do this in PostUp, but I just did it in my general firewall.

Maybe you are talking about "UPnP" or something like that. I don't know if it is possible to have it working when your VPN client really belongs to another subnet. Maybe you can try avoid masquerade on the wireguard server, but add static route for the VPN subnet in your router (with the route gateway being the LAN IP of the wg server), so that your router can be aware of the real source IP. (But Idk maybe UPnP would only work when the host is in the LAN broadcast domain, which means only bridging to it with an L2 VPN, like tap mode OpenVPN, might work)

@davidgo Thanks! sorry for the late answer, notifications for this post was falling into spam mail folder for some reason.. ok I'll try the IPTables rules and I'll be back later to tell how is it going.. Greetings!

@TomYan Hey Thanks! I'm answering later for email problems, sorry.. I do not use UPnP because some people say its not secure.. I'll try the IPTABLES rules and see how it works.. Thanks

@davidgo Hey! added the iptables rules to the server's wg config file with no luck.. this is the output on the CLI when I start wg tunnel on the server by the wg-quick command:
[#] ip link add WireGuard type wireguard
[#] wg setconf WireGuard /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add ip/24 dev WireGuard
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev WireGuard
[#] ufw route allow in on WireGuard out on eth0
Rule added
Rule added (v6)
[#] iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 63521 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.100.0.10:63521
[#] iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

Break out tcpdump and see what is happening at the packet level.

@davidgo Hi! ok I'll check it out how to use tcpdump and comment later.. thanks
